# STS and AccuBridge

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, accurev

Due to a problem I'm encountering with STS2.3.3.M2 and JUnit tests, I decided to try out the newest STS (v2.5.1RELEASE). I installed AccuBridge since Accurev is our version controller and I was trying to checkout a project from depot... except that my STS hangs when I try to select the depot.

Steps I did:
1. New > Project > Accurev > Checkout from AccuRev
2. Click Next
3. Pick either radio button and STS hangs

Nothing's wrong with any of my paths though. And, when I still try to connect with my older STS2.3.3.M2, I can still connect to Accurev. Btw, we're using Accurev 4.9...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that STS 2.5 is based on a vendor customization of Eclipse Helios 3.6, right?  As of the 2010.2 plugin for Eclipse, it is not necessarily compatible with versions other than Classic Eclipse, especially vendor customizations.  You may get some functionality, but not all.  This is being worked on for the 2010.3 AccuRev plugin, so for now I'd recommend that you stay with the 2.3.3 STS.

Hope this helps!
Cheers,
~James

Comment: Yes, STS 2.5 is based on Eclipse 3.6

Comment: hmm... true but i got it working before with 2.3.3 sts which is why i was wondering about it. unfortunately, i needed to test something with the newer sts (a bug 2.3.3 has with older junits) though i guess i need to wait for the next accubridge release until that happens. anyway, thanks! =)